# "relation does not exist" when running sync()

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm having an issue getting associations to work properly, please help! I'm running Node 10.15.0, Sequelize 4.42, PostgreSQL 10.6.

In my models index file I first create the association with `Review.belongsTo(Product)`, then sync the models `Product.sync({force: true}); Review.sync({force: true});`

and it's throwing this error: 
`Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "products" does not exist`

The line in the console immediately preceding this error is

> Executing (default): SELECT typname, typtype, oid, typarray FROM pg_type WHERE (typtype = 'b' AND typname IN ('hstore', 'geometry', 'geography')) OR (typtype = 'e')

I don't know if that gives any clues, but I'm not defining any of those fields or using any of those data types in my models.

If I remove the association definition from my model, it generates & syncs with the database as expected.

Any ideas?? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `sequelize.sync()` syncs all models and relationships you defined. `Review.sync({force: true});` should be call after callback of `Product.sync({force: true});`, therefore `products` is not existen

Comment: @huynhsamha that solved it! thank you so much!

`Product.sync({force: true})
  .then( () => {
    Review.sync({force: true});
  });`